# Can't set a checkbox with watir-webdriver

Tags: ruby, checkbox, automation, watir, watir-webdriver

I'm testing my app with tumblr and i have to log in and out as I go through procedures. While doing so, I'm having trouble clicking a checkbox that keeps popping up. How can I use watir-webriver to click it.

[image]

I've used the

```
browser.checkbox(:value => "recaptcha-anchor").set
```

and

```
browser.checkbox(:id => "recaptcha-anchor").set
```

and

```
browser.span(:id => "recaptcha-anchor").click
```

Comment: What happened when you tried the `browser.span(:id => "recaptcha-anchor").click `? Have you looked into the scripts to determine which element has the event listener?

Comment: Maybe a timing issue if you say it pops up. Consider trying .when_present.click

Comment: @titusfortner nothing happens, I tried `browser.span(:id => "recaptcha-anchor").when_present.click `

Comment: @JustinKo I'm not sure how to check which element has the event listener, I'm still considerably new with Ruby :\

Comment: When I click `Inspect Element` the `<div class="recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark" role="presentation"></div>` is the one highlighed.

Comment: Maybe you want to try `browser.span(:id => "recaptcha-anchor").div(class: => "recaptcha-checkbox-checkmark").click`?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work. I even added the `.when_present` method @JustinKo

Comment: Can you share a working example of the page? Without an example it is difficult to help debug the issue.

Comment: its the https://www.tumblr.com/login page @JustinKo

Comment: Sorry, I am not a tumblr user. Where is the checkbox?

Comment: If you keep logging in and out (which i havee to do) it will eventually pop up after trying to log in @JustinKo

Comment: Thanks for your help @JustinKo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In cases such as this one, I think it's worth accessing the checkbox directly using watir's checkbox method instead of using div or span or whichever element is wrapping that checkbox.

How many checkboxes do you have at this page? If there is only one then this might work:

`browser.checkbox(attribute: attribute-value).when_present.set`

It may also be worth adding binding.pry before manipulating the checkbox.

e.g.

binding.pry

browser.checkbox(attribute: attribute-value).when_present.set

If you do this, binding.pry will be executed first which will send you in a ruby console where you can experiment on how to manipulate the checkbox and other stuff. You need to install the 'pry' gem beforehand.

Good luck!

Comment: I gave up and started in python and am having the same trouble, do you know anything about how to do it in python?

Comment: No idea in Python but I'm pretty sure if you did the following steps then you'd be able to click the checkbox:
1.) install the 'pry' gem 2.) type in 'pry' in the terminal or command line (depends on your OS) and hit enter. 3.) type in require 'watir-webdriver' 4.) type in browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome/:firefox 5.) navigate to Tumblr using the browser window and do the steps that will take you to the checkbox page 6.) Go back to the terminal and try browser.checkbox.exists? 7.) then manipulate and experiment from there.

Answer (score 0):

try to get css uniq path and click by it:

```
browser.element(:css => %csspath).click
```

Comment: I'm not too sure how I would write the css path, but I might be able to figure it out. It would be the same as calling it to print right?

Comment: i use chrome "inspect element" and copy xpath or css
looks like 
    browser.element(:xpath =>'//*[@id="MobilePhone"])'.click

Answer (score 0):

- you don't have a checkbox, you have a **span** and a **div**
- add a binding.pry using the pry gem
- talk to your devs about how they are interacting with that "checkbox"
- it looks like the "checked/unchecked" value of this "checkbox" may be controlled in the span class attribute
- That's all I got... unconventional elements cause headaches for testers